# Nuget is trying to restore wrong version of the package, skipping revision number

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In my project I have a package added with version `1.0.1.0` and so is added like this in `packages.config` file

```
<package id="Stylesoft.Common.Dev" version="1.0.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

The nuget source I am using does have this package. But when I try to restore the package for the solution using nuget restore command like this

```
nuget restore Solution.sln
```

it tries to restore the package `Stylesoft.Common.Dev.1.0.1`, so basically skips the last zero i.e. revision number while restoring and so does not find it and so fails.

Any idea how I can make nuget to look for full exact version package and not skip the last zero?

Comment: What is your Visual Studio and Nuget version?

Comment: @Peska - nuget version - 5.5.1.6542 and visual studio version - Visual studio professional 2019 version 16.6.4

Answer (score 0):

There was a breaking change in NuGet 3.4
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#normalized-version-numbers

> When obtaining packages from a repository during install, reinstall,
> or restore operations, NuGet 3.4+ treats version numbers as follows:
>
> Leading zeroes are removed from version numbers:
>
> 1.00 is treated as 1.0 1.01.1 is treated as 1.1.1 1.00.0.1 is treated as 1.0.0.1
>
> A zero in the fourth part of the version number will be omitted
>
> 1.0.0.0 is treated as 1.0.0 1.0.01.0 is treated as 1.0.1
>
> SemVer 2.0.0 build metadata is removed
>
> 1.0.7+r3456 is treated as 1.0.7